# <?echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php')?> does not work in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

The following works fine on the Mac under MAMP and on my real domain but fails when running under WAMP:

```
<body id="<?echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php')?>">
```

Comment: Use `<?php echo` instead of `<?echo`

Comment: Does not work means that PHP code is not executed and gets sent to the browser?

Comment: Your WAMP environment has `short_open_tag` disabled (like it probably should be) http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
<body id="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php'); ?>">
```

Maybe you have turned off short tags.

If it's still not defined you can use:

```
<body id="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>">
```

In case your current file is the current script.

Comment: Enabling short open tag fixed the problem. Why should that be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

```
<title><?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php') == 'index'){ echo "Dashboard"; }else{ echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php'); } ?></title>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow. Please elaborate what this code does and why it helps to solve the original problem. Code-only answers are not considered to be good quality in StackOverflow. Thanks!